# using stringstream and ofstream to write long log file

Tags: c++, csv, io

I need to write the values of variables to a persistent file.  Each write operation should add one new line to the same file, and that file will end up having millions of lines of data from millions of write operations.  The code that I wrote below does indeed write to the file, but the problem is that it over-writes the same line again and again.  Also, I am not sure if I escaped the end of the line properly because it does not output multiple lines yet.  Can anyone show me how to modify the code below so that it writes as many lines of data as it is called upon to write?

```
#include <sstream>  
#include <string>  

void writeToFile(std::stringstream& ss){  
    using namespace std;  
    string myString = ss.str();  
    ofstream myfile;  
    myfile.open ("somefile.txt");  
    myfile << myString;  
    myfile.close();  
}  

void anotherFunction(){    
    using namespace std;
    stringstream mySS;
    mySS << someVar; mySS << ", "; mySS << var2;
    mySS << ", "; mySS << something; mySS << ", "; mySS << somethingelse; mySS << ", ";
    mySS << dayofweek; mySS << ", "; mySS << time; mySS << ", ";
    mySS << whichbone; mySS << ", "; mySS << name; mySS << "\n" << endl;
    writeToFile(mySS);
}

void aThirdFunction(){
    using namespace std;    
    stringstream mySS;    
    mySS << someVar; mySS << ", "; mySS << var2;    
    mySS << ", "; mySS << var3; mySS << ", "; mySS << fourthVar; mySS << ", ";    
    mySS << fifthVar; mySS << ", "; mySS << sixthVar; mySS << "\n" << endl;    
    writeToFile(mySS);    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open the output file for appending: `myfile.open ("somefile.txt", ios_base::app);`
Otherwise it is truncated to 0 length each time your reopen it.

Comment: +1 and credit for the answer for hitting the nail on the head.  This works now.  Impressive response time.  The only thing your answer does not include is that the "\n" became redundant and was adding a blank line after adding your fix.